# POST not grabbing all form variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, mysqli

Trying to figure out why my code does not send over all POST data. The code is used on main page to get request information stored in db and used on separate page to post status updates made by me to DB. Its basically the same, except variable names.

Note: I have searched here a lot. Ive used var_dump that shows only 'content' data in the array. Im not fully comfortable with js but can follow some of it. Hence the code below is a template that Ive edited and tested on one page before trying to expand to another. Thats where the issue is. I am not sure why it works for one and not the other. Apologies if this is considered duplicate of anything, but I didnt find a good answer in similar post that would explain why.
admin.php:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="share">
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">

         <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="">
               <img src="../logo.png" style="height:60px; width:60px; float:left; margin-right:3px;" />
               <textarea name="content1" id="content1" cols="40" rows="10"  class="form-control message" style="height: 60px; width:450px; overflow: hidden;"></textarea> 
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-7">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="btn-group">
                        <select name="avatar" id="avatar" class="form-control-issue-avatar"> <----whats not sending
                           <option value="0" selected="selected">Author</option>
                           <option value="per1">P</option>
                           <option value="per2">W</option>
                        </select> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-5">
                  <input type="submit" value="Post" class="post_button">                               
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

</form>
```

Here is the insert.php:

```
if(isSet($_POST['content1'], $_POST['avatar']))

{
 $content1=$_POST['content1'];
 $avatar=$_POST['avatar']; // <--- comes back NULL
$sql_in= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT comment,comment_id,status_time FROM comments order by comment_id desc");
$r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_in);
}
```

and lastly the post.js that calls it:

```
 $(function() {

$(".post_button").click(function() {

 var element = $(this);

 var test = $("#content1").val();

 var dataString = 'content1='+ test;

 if(test=='')
 {
 alert("Please Enter Some Text");

}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
url: "insert.php",
 data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){



$("#display").after(html);

document.getElementById('content1').value='';
$("#flash").hide();

}


});
}


return false;
});

});
```

the var_dump etc:

```
Array ( [content1] => sass )
C:\wamp64\www\post\insert.php:32:
 array (size=1)
'content1' => string 'sass' (length=4)
```

Comment: I'm confused about how you think you're sending the value for avatar if it's not being fetched in your JS and not being sent in the data, or am I missing something?

Comment: You are only sending one variable. Why don't you just serialize the form instead

Comment: Well thats what I'm trying to figure out. The js is same as function used in the first page. The first page has no issues grabbing ALL parts (IE email, username, textinput of issue) ..I have no clue. I tried editing to use querySelectorAll with no fix @BarryWalsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add id attribute to the form and then use `serialize()` on the form to get all data from the form to pass via ajax to php

```
<form id='formid'>


$.ajax({
data: $('#formid').serialize(),
//other Ajax stuff 

});
```

Comment: made the suggested edits by "adding" that line to the existing, didnt see a difference. I maybe using it wrong though? var dump still only showed:

C:\wamp64\www\post\insert.php:32:
array (size=1)
  'content1' => string 'testttt' (length=7)

Comment: The serialize should get you all form contents. You added id to form and serialize() like I said?

Comment: You have data key twice. Remove the data: dataString

Comment: Pleasure friend :)